# Hide other item when one is clicked without define any class in react accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

I implement the accordion but now I want to show only one particular item at a time. I know there are plenty answers available in this platform regarding this same problem but I can't find any suitable solution. Actually, I don't want to add any class in the active item and don't want to do that with CSS. With pure JavaScript, how can I achieve this?
Here is my code:

```
   const PerFAQ = ({ ques, ans }) => {
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false)
    return (
        <>
            <li>
                <a onClick={() => setIsShown(!isShown)}>{ques}
                    {
                        !isShown ? <BsChevronDown /> : <BsChevronUp />
                    }
                </a>
                {
                    isShown && <ul>
                        <li>
                            {ans}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        </>
    )
}
```

Willing to share more code if needed.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me. You want this React component implemented in pure JavaScript, am I correct?

Comment: I think I am not correct, and you mean without css by pure JS, not without React. This code actually hides a single item, please provide a bit more information on what you are up to. Keep in mind that you know what you are doing in your application, but we know nothing about your code. We might guess it, but this time I have no clue. Thanks.

Comment: yes , in pure JavaScript , I want to hide other items, when clicking one

Comment: Now I get it. Sorry my bad, it should have been clear to me.

Comment: If you have any solution , please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by lifting the isShown state up.

For example:

```js
const ListItem = ({visible, onExpand}) => {
   return(
      <div>
          <button onClick={onExpand}>Expand</button>
          {visible && <p>your content</p>}
      </div>
   );
}

const List = ({items}) => {
   const [visibleIdx, setVisibleIdx] = useState(-1);
   return (
       <div>
            <ListItem visible={visibleIdx == 0} onExpand={() => setVisibleIdx(0)} />
            <ListItem visible={visibleIdx == 1} onExpand={() => setVisibleIdx(1)} />
       </div>
   )
}
```

Edit:
It might be unclear what I meant.
The React components form a tree hierarchy. Each item has children. The state of a component is stored by the component itself. You can pass these components down to its children, but cannot pass it up, to its parents.
If you need to access the state from the parent, the only solution is to lift it up. That means you need to move the state to the parent component, and that component needs to pass it down to its children.

Comment: ok , got it. now suppose I have to add another ListItem, then should I have to do something like this :  <ListItem visible={visibleIdx == 2} onExpand={() => setVisibleIdx(2)} />

Comment: You can edit the code you provided like in the exampe. Notice that in my example, the isShown state is not in the list item, but in the list itself. That is the key to the solution, to not store isShown in the item itself, but to store it where you use these items.